# React component with D3 chart renders too many times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have this component:

```
export default function ThirdSlide({ userTopArtistsAllTime }) {
  const newref = useRef();

  const { items } = userTopArtistsAllTime;

  let genresObj = {};
  let genres = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    createPie(genresObj);
  }, [genresObj]);

  const getData = () => {
    items
      ? items.map((item) => {
          genres.push(item.genres[0]);
          genres.push(item.genres[1]);
        })
      : console.log("null");

    if (genres.length > 1) {
      for (let value in genres) {
        let key = genres[value];
        genresObj[key] ? genresObj[key]++ : (genresObj[key] = 1);
      }
    }
  };

  const createPie = (data) => {
    ....
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Background>
        <div>
          <span>What genres do you favorite artists fit in?</span>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ marginLeft: "50px", marginTop: "200px" }}
          ref={newref}
        ></div>
      </Background>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

The createPie(data) function just creates a chart in D3 and its working okay. The problem that I have is that react renders the SVG 5 times instead of just once and I think it has to do with useEffect and my props?

How can I restructure this code so createPie is called just once ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `useEffect` dependency is `genresObj` and in every render a new empty object is created by `let genresObj = {};` so `useEffect` run in every render.

You can depend `useEffect` on `items` and move variables inside useEffect scope.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let genresObj = {};
    let genres = [];
    getData();
    createPie(genresObj);
  }, [items]);
```

However, for code actually works you need pass down parameters to `getData` as well.

Comment: You can change getData function to accept `item` as parameter and return `genresObj` and get rid of those two variables. Then use it like this `createPie(getData(items))` in one line of code.

Answer (score 2):

Adding more color to Makan's answer.

`useEffect` will rerun the effect [every time any one of its dependencies changes](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).  To know if a dependency changes, useEffect uses `===` to determine whether two consecutive dependencies are equal.

In JS, `{} === {}` evaluates to `false`. So in the eyes of `useEffect`, `genresObj` is different every time, causing it to recall your D3 logic.

Changing useEffect to depend on `userTopArtistsAllTime`, like has been suggested, makes sense.  With that change, you will recall the effect as often as `userTopArtistsAllTime` changes `===` equality.  If you make that change and you still see the `useEffect` firing too often, check to see what logic is constructing `userTopArtistsAllTime`.

Now, it seems that you currently have a bug with your `getData` implementation.  Make it a pure function of its arguments to correctly handle side effects.

Comment: I managed to do some stuff, made it a pure function and before this it was rendering like 8-9 times, I understand now that its because how react works, but still now as I changed the dependency of useEffect to my userTopArtistsAllTime / items , it still renders 2 times, one time its an empty SVG(I guess it means data is not there yet) and the second time its the SVG I want.